# How Antioxidants affects Metabolism?

Tags: diet, nutrition, metabolism

I'd like to know how antioxidants affects the metabolism and which ones are essential for metabolism processes.

Comment: How is this related to exercise? Per the FAQ, we only accept nutrition questions *as related to exercise*.

Comment: 'Cause antioxidants are part of nutrition i want to know how it affects the metabolism, as growing muscles, cell regeneration, etc. all those things are related to exercise , performance and cause some antioxidants in high concentrations damage health.

Comment: I don't see any relation to exercise here, too.

Comment: This question can be re-opened if it can be modified to be more closely related to fitness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antioxidants basically neutralize free radicals in your body by providing them with the electron they are missing (remember chemistry class). Free radicals are dangerous to have in your body because they are missing an electron. They float around your body looking to steal an electron from something. If it steals it from a healthy cell, there is a chance that the cell will mutate (that can cause a number of bad things, including cancer). Antioxidants have an extra electron. When an antioxidant meets a free radical, it gladly gives its extra electron thereby rendering it harmless. I don’t know if it will boost your metabolism or not, but getting plenty of antioxidants is critical for long term helth.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer!
By the way, you know something about high concentrations of these antioxidants? I heard that in high concentrations can damage your health also.